# fetching data from mysql to display on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start(); // First thing... every time
require_once("connect.php");    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: login.php'); the top
exit; // Always include after redirect.
 }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $sql = "UPDATE user SET attendance1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
 mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

 $query="SELECT lastname FROM user WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['username'] . ";"; 
 $result=mysql_query($query); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
  $_SESSION[lastname] = $row[lastname]; 
 header("Location: thankyou.html", true, 303); // Look up "303: See Other"
   exit;
 }
?>
```

above is my php code. What i want to do is display the lastname from the database onto the webpage.

code on webpage is

```
Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?>.
```

the issue is that the lastname is not displayed after welcome

Comment: and the problem? you already seem to know how to query a db and store in a session , so what's the issue?

Comment: @Dagon sorry i have edited it now. lastname not displaying after welcome

Comment: You're missing quotes around `$_SESSION['username']` in the `SELECT` query...

Comment: then i assume last name is not set in the session.

Comment: @Jacob Where did you actually set `$_SESSION['lastname']`? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

i see that u r just getting the display i.e., select display from table. if you need lastname and display then you should be doing Select display,lastname from user.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work.

```
<?php
session_start(); // First thing... every time
require_once("connect.php");    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: login.php'); the top
exit; // Always include after redirect.
 }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET attendance1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['attendance1']) . "' WHERE username = '" . $userName . "'";
 mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

 $query="SELECT lastname FROM user WHERE username = '" . $userName . "';"; 
 $result=mysql_query($query); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
  $_SESSION['display'] = $row['lastname']; 
  $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname']; 
 header("Location: thankyou.html", true, 303); // Look up "303: See Other"
   exit;
 }
?>
```

Comment: display is my lastname, i have edited my post to make it easier to understand

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly. Please check.

Comment: I have no 'display' field in mysql, why is there a 'display' in your code?

Comment: Your code says "SELECT display FROM user WHERE username ........." So you should have a display field in the table. Otherwise please correct your question.

Comment: sorry thats meant to be lastname

Comment: I modified my answer. However you have to understand How it need to be done. Also work on your accepted rate. It's just 25%.

Comment: i still dont understand why you have 'display' there. I do not have any fields in my database named dispay.

Comment: You probably talk about `$_SESSION['display'] = $row['lastname'];` Don't worry about it. I thought you need this session as well. If you don't need remove that line. And even in that code. It get only 'lastname' from the database NOT the 'display'. 'display' is the session name.

Comment: so if i remove it im back to my original code i posted above which does not work

Comment: Mr. Check the difference of your code and my code. Even after you modifying your question couple of times. You code has ` $_SESSION[lastname] = $row[lastname]; ` which is wrong implementation. . And my code has ` $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname']; ` If you don't see any difference let me know I will delete my answer. Really waste of time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used apostrophes surrounding array keys line 15 so PHP is looking for a key matching a key name corresponding to a constant named lastname.

Comment: PHP will actually assume that a constant that hasn't been defined was supposed to be a string. It will issue a warning about the undefined constant, but interpret it as a quoted string. So even though it's terrible practice, that will still work.

Comment: Didn't know this was still working ... Anyway, I guess that the redirected page just can't simply display php instructions as it's html file !